# What causes Permission denied errors when deleting files?

Tags: php, linux, file, permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to delete `/var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/noname3.php` using PHP.  As shown below, the file's owner and group is phped, it is group writable, and Michael belongs to the phped group.  I am using Centos with Apache.

```
[Michael@devserver NewFolder1]$ pwd
/var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1
[Michael@devserver NewFolder1]$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 phped phped 15 Jan  5 07:02 noname3.php
[Michael@devserver NewFolder1]$ groups Michael
Michael : Michael www phped
[Michael@devserver NewFolder1]$
```

My PHP script is:

```
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user().'<br>';
echo($dirname.'</br>');
unlink($dirname);
```

And the output follows:

```
Current script owner: Michael
/var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/noname3.php

An error occurred in script '/var/www/main/application/classes/library.php' on line 477: unlink(/var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/noname3.php): Permission denied (error no: 2)
```

Why can't Michael delete the file?

Comment: Well PHP scripts are running with user www-data no matter what user you are starting the php process with so it wont help to have the file owner "Michael" cause PHP is not running with the rights that "Michael" got but www-data. Try exec("chown Michael $dirname");

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Yes, but in permissive mode.

Comment: @Steini  Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Michael that is being blocked from deleting this file, but Apache.
You should set apache as owner of this file and your script will work:

```
chmod 755 -R NewFolder1/
chown -R apache:apache NewFolder1/
```

Now the problem is that user Michael will not have any ftp privileges over this folder.
If you want ftp privileges as well, try that:

```
chmod 775 -R /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/
chown -R Michael:apache /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/
```

The -R stands for "recursive" meaning that all files and subfolders of NewFolder1 will inherit the same permissions. However this is not really recommended -especially if you are on a shared hosting server.

To check the file permissions, use

```
ls -la /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/
```

Solution #2:

Login as root first!!!
if you are logged in as different user, type:

```
su -
```

and then provide the root password.

Then, navigate to a local directory (ie: /usr/local/sbin) and create a script called "delete-file" and put the following lines in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && {
        echo "usage: $0 <filename>"
        exit 1
}

file=`echo $1`

rm -f $file

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "File has been deleted from system!" || echo "Failed to delete the file!"
```

Then make this file executable:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/sbin/delete-file
```

Then edit /etc/sudoers to add apache:

```
...
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear.
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".
#
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults:apache     !requiretty ###ADD THIS LINE!

#
# Refuse to run if unable to disable echo on the tty. This setting should also be
# changed in order to be able to use sudo without a tty. See requiretty above.
#
...
```

AT THE END OF THE SAME FILE:

```
...
## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

### ADD THIS NEXT LINE:
apache  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/delete-file
```

Modify your php script to look like that:

```
<?php
...
$filename = "/var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/file-to-delete.php";
shell_exec('sudo -S /usr/local/sbin/delete-file '.$filename);
...
?>
```

Now this should be able to delete files no matter who their owner is!

Comment: I didn't show it, however, apache also belongs to phped.  And as I showed, isn't the processing being run by Michael and not apache?  `[Michael@devserver NewFolder1]$ groups apache
apache : apache www phped`

Comment: The point here is not who owns (or runs) the script: /var/www/main/application/classes/library.php but who owns the file that you want to unlink (ie: /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/noname3.php) Just do this: ls -la /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/ to see the permissions of the file you want to unlink and maybe post the results here...

Comment: I did show the permissions at the top of the original post.  I didn't use the `-a` flag but that just shows hidden files.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that... I see that you have 775 permissions to the file. Does the containing folder have the same permissions and owner? If not, fix that. If yes, try to change the group from phped to apache: chown -R phped:apache /var/www/main/user_resources/documents/NewFolder1/NewFolder1/ and let me know what happens.

Comment: Parent folders are either the same or Michael:www with same permissions all the way down to `/var/www` which is owned by root.  As shown, both apache and Michael belong to www, so I don't see any problems (obviously, problems exist, I just don't see them!)

Comment: I just tried deleting the file from the command line as Michael, and still can't delete it, so it has nothing to do with PHP/Apache but just Linux file permissions.

Comment: @user1032531 I have made an edit to my answer, giving you an alternative solution -which I have used also in the past (for a different purpose -to dynamically add/delete system users) and worked like a charm! Give it a try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68232/discussion-between-captain-theo-and-user1032531).

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you show, you should be able to delete the file.  If you can't, you likely (definitely) did not log the Linux user which is used for PHP out and then logged him back in.