# How to log in and out the Linux PHP user?

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I operate PHP using the Linux user "dummy".  I just added dummy to a new Linux group called "new_group".

How do I log dummy out and then log him back in so he has permissions for files of group new_group?

Do I need to reboot the server or restart Apache, or is there a less invasive way?

Comment: Downvote?  Yes, it relates to servers, but I believe is more pertinent to programming and don't believe is off topic.

Comment: Not my downvote, but probably because of the *dipshit* thing. Some are just a bit over-sensitive; *who knows*.

Comment: What exactly are you asking (and what have you tried)?

Comment: Oh, the dipshit username.  If you ever spent the past day messing around with it, you might even refer to your self as one as I have.  Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782951/what-causes-permission-denied-errors-when-deleting-files

Comment: @kingkero How to log in and out the Linux PHP user.  As described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782951/what-causes-permission-denied-errors-when-deleting-files, I've been struggling to figure out how to delete a file.  Turns out it had nothing to do with PHP or Apache, but was because my PHP user was given permission of a given group, but never logged off and back on to make it effective.  I finally realized this was required to do so from the shell, so it must be the same from within PHP.  I would expect I could reboot the server or restart Apache, but just guessing.  What is best?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Obviously, I was referring to myself as the dipshit and not you.  Just wanted to make sure it wasn't misunderstood.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Good!  Better edit my post so I don't offend others :)

Comment: May as well. I on the other hand, have a lot thicker skin than most lol - *Cheers*